# Group By and Sort a Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I would like to group rows in a tensorflow dataset by a key and select top k rows in each group by some value. This is easily doable ex. in Pandas or SQL, but not so obvious in TF.

I found in tf.experimental [group_by_window](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/group_by_window) and [group_by_reducer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/group_by_reducer), but I can't figure out how to sort a dataset by a specific column.

My dataset has Dict structure for the rows. What I am looking for is smth like:

```
from tensorflow.data.experimental import group_by_window

def key_f(row):
    return row['id']  

def reduce_func(key, ds):
    # sort by a value - except there is no method like this...
    ds=ds.sort(by='value')
    return ds.take(5)

t = group_by_window(key_func = key_f, reduce_func = reduce_func, window_size=100)

ds = dataset.apply(t)
```

UPDATE: Here is an example. Let's say I want to group by 'id' and sort by 'start' in each group, all within TF:

```
pd.DataFrame([{ 'id': 1, 'input_a': 0.0, 'start': 5},
            {'id': 1, 'input_a': 10.0, 'start': 15},
            {'id': 2, 'input_a': 20.0, 'start': 25},
            {'id': 2, 'input_a': 30.0, 'start': 35}])
```

Comment: I added an example in the question. But at this point I don't think there is a simple way to do it (without converting to pandas and back for example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this,

```
from tensorflow.data.experimental import group_by_window

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df))
def key_f(row):
  return row['id']  

def reduce_func(key, ds):
    
    ds=ds \  # -> continuation
    # we create a batch of all the data in the group
    # the only caveat: you need to know the maximum number of data points
    # that can be in a batch - set it to that
    .batch(100) \
    # In the map function get get sorted indices using start column
    # and gather accordingly from all columns
    .map(
        lambda x: dict([(k, tf.gather(x[k], tf.argsort(x["start"]))) for k, v in x.items()])
    ) \
    # Unbatch data 
    .unbatch()

    return ds.take(5)

t = group_by_window(key_func = key_f, reduce_func = reduce_func, window_size=100)

ds = dataset.apply(t)
```